# Can't find lr_db_connect step

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I'm trying to connect to db using LoadRunner following [this](https://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/156450_t_how_to_add_a_database_connection.htm) tutorial. Problem is I can't find "lr_db_connect" from 3rd step. Couldn't find any info whether this method is deprecated right now or moved somewhere else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add the version of LoadRunner you are using and the script protocol(s) you have selected in the new script dialog.

Comment: version:  12.53 build 1203;
protocol:  ODBC

Comment: I saw you figured it out

Comment: Thanks to your comment !

Answer (score 0):

I've choose wrong protocol (ODBC instead of CVuser or JavaVuser). It's not specified in tutorial which one you suppose to use.